# How to troubleshoot update-manager?

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

My `update-manager` is not behaving correctly. How do I troubleshoot it? Are there any logs written specifically by the GUI?

I have 16.04 with Openbox for WM/desktop. Most of the "unneeded" packages are removed so that might be the issue.

When I start `update-manager` it updates the repositories correctly and displays the list of new packages. When I click the Install Now button it displays the small Software Updater window with a progress bar but that window disappears almost instantly. No error boxes are shown. No upgrade is performed.

Absolutely nothing appears in `/var/log/apt/history.log`. `/var/log/syslog` receives this one record which does not look like an error:

```
Dec  8 13:53:16 host-name org.debian.apt[1026]: 13:53:16 AptDaemon.Worker [INFO]:
 Committing packages:
   dbus.Array([dbus.String('linux-headers-4.4.0-53#auto'), 
   dbus.String('linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic#auto'), 
   dbus.String('linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic#auto'), 
   dbus.String('linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic#auto')], 
    signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], 
    signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], 
    signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], 
    signature=dbus.Signature('s')), 
   dbus.Array([dbus.String('ghostscript'), dbus.String('ghostscript-x'), 
   dbus.String('libgs9'), 
   dbus.String('libgs9-common'), 
   dbus.String('libprocps4'), 
   dbus.String('linux-generic'), 
   dbus.String('linux-headers-generic'), 
   dbus.String('linux-image-generic'), 
   dbus.String('linux-libc-dev'), 
   dbus.String('procps')],
    signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], 
    signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
```

I tried `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* && sudo apt-get update`, didn't help.

When I start `update-manager` from a terminal it prints immediately:

```
/usr/bin/update-manager:28: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk
WARNING:root:can not import unity GI cannot import name Dbusmenu, introspection typelib not found
```

And nothing more is ever printed in the terminal until `update-manager` closes.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` work correctly but they "hold back" the new kernel. I have to use `sudo apt-get upgrade linux-generic` to upgrade everything.

It is possible that this issue only happens when a new kernel is available. I'll keep an eye on that.

#### Update:

Running `gksudo update-manager` does solve the problem. The updates are installed correctly, including the new kernel.

My `update-manager` is usually started by `update-notifier` ran at the session start by my account's user. Still it was able to update the repository, probably via aptd.

How to run update-manager properly is probably a separate question. But the original question stands: is there a way to learn why exactly update-manager fails to chooch?

#### Update 2:

My real problem was that I wasn't running any PolKit agents. So update-manager wasn't able to ask me for a password. My question is still valid though: how I would find that out without guesswork?

Comment: Does it only happen when some system internal files need to be updated? Does `sudo update-manager` help?

Comment: `sudo update-manager` does help! How did I not try this myself? Weird.

Comment: So you probably have the same problem as I do. For me it started after I let do updates using different than usual user account.  After that polkit started to do stuff like that (closing windows instead of asking for a password; `gparted` also has difficulties). Seems like some kind of permission conflict but I can't find which file is responsible.

Comment: @pvc Today I was able to confirm that updates not involving kernel install just fine. The update was for libc6 and for the Intel video driver.

Comment: same situation in 18.04, `sudo update-manager` also helps